# How to nest an anchor element within a table cell?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to create this using javascript but am not getting it correct:

```
<td>
    <a href="https://google.com">
        Google
    </a>
</td>
```

My current JS looks like this:

```
var value = "Google";
var draftLink = document.createElement("a");

draftLink.href = "https://google.com";
draftLink.innerHTML = value;

td.innerHTML = draftLink;
```

I am ending up with

```
<td>
    https://google.com
<td>
```

Comment: Instead of `td.innerHTML=` use `td.appendChild(draftLink);`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `td` variable gets the table cell that you want, use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) instead:

```
var value = "Google";
var draftLink = document.createElement("a");
draftLink.href = "https://google.com";
draftLink.innerHTML = value;

td.appendChild(draftLink);
```

```js
var value = "Google";
var draftLink = document.createElement("a");
var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0];
draftLink.href = "https://google.com";
draftLink.innerHTML = value;

td.appendChild(draftLink);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```